# I'm learning and tyring to create a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a for loop and I want the output to be this:

```
0 is even.
1 is odd.
2 is even.
3 is odd.
4 is even.
5 is odd.
6 is even.
7 is odd.
8 is even.
9 is odd.
```

And all I have gotten this far:

```
my_range=range(0,11)

for i in my_range:
    print(i)
```

and the output is all the numbers:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do is, change your print function as -

```
print(i," is", 'even.' if (i % 2 == 0) else 'odd.')
```

Comment: Cool, I never thought of using the print function with multiple arguments!  I had `print(str(i) + " is " + ("odd." if (i % 2) else "even."))` but your method avoids having to convert numbers to strings first

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use here is conditional statements along with 'String Interpolation' in python.

The Below code will give you the desired output:

```
my_range=range(0,11)

for i in my_range:
    if i%2:
        print("{} is odd".format(i))
    else:
        print("{} is even".format(i))
```